# Logging of incorrect row in SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I newbie to SQL Server Integration Services and I have a problem:

Data loaded from file looks like this:

```
1 'a' 'b'
2 'a' 'b'
1 'c' 'd'
```

And this rows would be loaded in table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   ID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    A nvarchar NOT NULL,
    B nvarchar NOT NULL
);
```

Cause of `ID` is primary key third row in input data could not be loaded, and I want to load correct rows (first and second or third and second) and send to log incorrect row.

Comment: there are two ways... a) Remove primary key ..make as ID Not Null (b) Concatenate the values and then insert i.e. 1 'a,c' 'b,d' 2 'a' 'b'

Comment: @Niladri There are a fixed table structure.

Comment: then 2nd option will work..Concatenate the values and then insert i.e. 1 'a,c' 'b,d' 2 'a' 'b'

Answer (score 1):

Check this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628352/etl-ssis-redirecting-error-rows-to-a-seperate-table

It has all the steps you need to have the error records stored somewhere else.

Comment: Exactly what I would have recommended.